# Get part of JSON object

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I'm playing with Google Maps and Geocoding (converting Address to lang/lat coordinates). Everything works fine so far and I'm getting an answer from the google maps server with a file:

```
$address = urlencode( $address );
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&sensor=false";
$content = file_get_contents( $url );
echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $content );
echo '</pre>';
```

Point is that I don't need all that information.

**Questions**

*A* How do I get only a part of the JSON object? 
 (*Example*: I only need `'results'->'address_components'->'type' = 'country';`.)

*B* Can I reduce the content of the returned (google) file somehow as I don't need everything?

**Update**

I need to add part of the data to a json object. So decoding & then encoding seems like a loss of energy & time (at this point). Any ideas if I'd be better (faster) off with requesting a XML object? (The final set of objects is pretty large. This is why I should really care about performance.)

---

Example JSON answer from Google Maps maps server (file content):

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "28",
               "short_name" : "28",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Sellhorner Weg",
               "short_name" : "Sellhorner Weg",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Behringen",
               "short_name" : "Behringen",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bispingen",
               "short_name" : "Bispingen",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Soltau-Fallingbostel",
               "short_name" : "Soltau-Fallingbostel",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Niedersachsen",
               "short_name" : "NDS",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Deutschland",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "29646",
               "short_name" : "29646",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Sellhorner Weg 28, 29646 Bispingen, Deutschland",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 53.118080,
               "lng" : 9.966859999999999
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 53.11942898029150,
                  "lng" : 9.96820898029150
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 53.11673101970850,
                  "lng" : 9.965511019708496
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Access the part that you want, then write out a new file just using that subarray?

Comment: Part B is really about googles API, and should be a separate question, or you should change the title to be googlemaps specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($content, true);
$countries = array_filter($array['results']['address_components'], function ($a) {
    return in_array('country', $a['types']);
});

var_dump($countries);
```

Gives you all `address_components` which have a type `'country'`. Probably that's only going to be one, but it *may* be more than one. This syntax requires PHP 5.3+ BTW.

> Can I reduce the content of the returned (google) file somehow as I don't need everything?

Just take the parts of the decoded `$array` you need and forget the rest. If you want, `json_encode` it again.

Comment: Aside from v5.3+ (which is not sure to be available on the server), a straight +1. Sadly it's not _really_ what I'm searching for. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @kaiser For PHP 5.2 you can formulate this using `create_function`. As for your updated question: You will hardly find another solution as compact and as **efficient**. It's really not a big deal to decode and encode such a tiny snippet of JSON. Trying to do any sort of manual string parsing and manipulation is much more effort and much more error prone. XML will have roughly the same overhead, since you need to parse it as well, but *may* be slightly more efficient if you read the stream little by little and copy the parts you need out as-is.